# Get user(merchant) ID once the app is installed

Tags: shopify

**Background:**

- I am making an app which will be a public app and will put it on Shopify App Store.
- I have completed with the [OAuth](https://help.shopify.com/en/api/getting-started/authentication/oauth) process and I get `access_token` and `scope` in return which is good. I can now use this token and send API requests with `X-Shopify-Access-Token` in the header.
- But, for my database design, I need the user details as well, like `user ID` or `email ID` for example. However, I read the [docs](https://help.shopify.com/en/api/getting-started/authentication/oauth#step-4-making-authenticated-requests)(scroll up a bit) and it suggested in the `caution` section that email address is not reliable to identify the user(merchant). I also gave a read on access modes which is `online` and `offline`, and in my case, I would need an `offline` access token.

**Question:**

- How would I get a User ID from Shopify during app install so that I could uniquely identify each merchant?
- One of the reasons I would want to have this is because a single merchant could have(or see) multiple stores linked with my app and I wish to show them details for each store under a single user account.

Answer (score 2):

When a merchant installs your App, during the oAuth flow, you are presented with the shop name. That is unique, and will always be present for incoming calls to your App from Shopify.

You do not mess around with email, or user ID's. You simply persist the access token you got in your data store, with the shop name.

If you wanted to group by a merchant name, you know each Shop object provides the shop owner details. So you can always dig those out and store them along with the shop name, allowing you to show one merchant, many stores.

Comment: Ok, I figured out that the `myshopify_domain` key is going to be unique from what I received from this [API](https://help.shopify.com/en/api/reference/store-properties/shop#show) even though I change the shop name. Even better would be to use shop's `id` itself. I also got a bit of shop owner details like `email`,`customer_email`, `phone`, `country_name` etc but not sure what key would remain unique through out and is not subjected to change?

Comment: Use myshopify_domain. It is unique and never changes. Cannot change. There is no such thing as a shop ID in Shopify, other than the myshopify_domain.

Comment: Ok, but what about grouping? How do I know that 2 shops have the same owner? Anything I can use from the aforementioned keys?

Comment: I already told you. Use an API call to get the shop details, scrape out the owner details, and use that to determine your grouping.

Comment: I mentioned the keys I get in my first comment. But which one can I rely on?

Comment: Use the key in your pocket. Reliable, easy to find, fits well, you've used it before and you have a spare hidden under the doormat.

Comment: Which key though?